# Como executar uma função após dois ou mais eventos assíncronos?

Tags: javascript, concorrência, manipulador-de-evento

Eu tenho um script jQuery que inicia duas ou mais operações assíncronas ao mesmo tempo, e gostaria de executar um *callback* quando **todas** elas estiverem concluídas. Um exemplo seria iniciar uma animação para esconder a página atual, enquanto faço uma requisição Ajax para carregar o conteúdo da próxima página. Tanto a animação pode terminar primeiro, quanto a requisição. Após **ambas** estarem terminadas, gostaria de exibir a página nova.

Eu não gostaria que a página nova fosse exibida [antes que a anterior estivesse totalmente escondida](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/68jAT/), nem que o fosse [antes de seu conteúdo estar pronto](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/68jAT/2/). De modo que o callback final não deve estar nem em um nem em outro evento.

Como fazer? De preferência, estou buscando por uma solução genérica, que funcione com dois ou mais eventos assíncronos simultâneos (é raro, mas poderia por exemplo ter de fazer mais de uma requisição Ajax simultânea, e só executar o *callback* após ter todos os resultados).

<sub>Nota: fiz a pergunta para JavaScript, no geral, mas uma solução específica para jQuery (por exemplo, algo envolvendo `Deferred`s ou `Promise`s) também estaria de bom tamanho.</sub>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Como você mencionou, você pode usar jQuery [`Deferred`s](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) (algo como "adiado") e [`Promise`s](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Promise) (promessas).

Você chama todas as ações que deseja que ocorram concorrentemente dentro de um [`$.when(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/):

```
$.when(acao1, acao2)
```

Note que essas ações devem retornar promessas para que possam ser utilizadas no *deferred*.

`when`, então, retorna um `Deferred` para todas aquelas promessas. É como um objeto para verificar todas as promessas no futuro. Então, você pode chamar [`then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) (ou mesmo outras funções de `Deferred`, como `done` e `fail`) com o que você quer que ocorra após que **todas as promessas forem cumpridas** ou que **pelo menos uma promessa não seja cumprida** (erro).

```
$.when(acao1, acao2).then(
  function(resultadoAcao1, resultadoAcao2) {
    // roda depois de acao1 e acao2 terminarem
  }, 
  function(resultadoAcaoErro) {
    // a primeira ação com erro termina aqui com o resultado do erro
  }
});
```

Em caso de sucesso, os resultados das ações são passados para o primeiro callback de `then` na ordem que as ações foram chamadas. Caso qualquer ação resulte em um erro, o segundo callback é chamado com esse erro. As outras ações são ignoradas nesse caso. (Veja exemplo [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/XLfPh/)).

Seu exemplo [fica assim](http://jsfiddle.net/68jAT/6/) (sem tratamento de erro):

```
$.when(
    // Ação 1: esconder a página
    $(".pagina:eq(0)").hide(Math.random()*4000).promise(),
    // Ação 2: carregar a nova
    $.getJSON('http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Products?$format=json'))
.then(function (hidden, jsonRequest) {
    $(".pagina:eq(1)")
        .find("strong")
        .text(jsonRequest[0].value[0].Name)
    $(".pagina:eq(1)").show(2000);
});
```

Note que alterei `getJSON` para buscar um JSON na internet, e que chamo [`promise`](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) para poder usar `hide` como um deferred para sua animação (`getJSON` já retorna uma promessa).

Comment: Ótima resposta, na verdade já tinha lido sobre o `when` mas não me lembrava dele. E isso de chamar o `promise` no retorno do `hide` é novidade pra mim, achei que fosse ser um obstáculo para se usar `Promise`s mas vejo que não é. +1 e aceito!

Answer (score 6):

O fato dos browsers usaram um único thread para o código JavaScript da página facilita bastante, pois há a garantia de que uma função invocada execute do início ao fim antes que uma outra função concorrente o faça (i.e. não há problema de concorrência, cada *event handler* como um todo pode ser considerado atômico). Desse modo, é simples implementar um semáforo, que acumula os resultados dos *callbacks* individuais e só chama o *callback* final depois que todas as chamadas individuais estiverem completas:

```js
/* Recebe o número de operações assíncronas, e o callback a ser executado no final */
function semaforo(numero, callback) {
    var array = []; // Acumula os resultados de cada evento assíncrono individual

    /* Retorna um proxy a ser usado no lugar do event handler 
       Os argumentos são o índice daquele evento em particular, e o handler verdadeiro
    */
    return function proxy(indice, fn) {
        if ( !fn ) fn = function() { };
        return function handler() {
            array[indice] = fn.apply(this, arguments); // Chama o handler e guarda o result.
            if ( --numero == 0 )             // Se todos os eventos terminaram,
                callback.apply(this, array); // chama o callback com os resultados
        }
    }
}
```

Exemplo de uso:

```js
var proxy = semaforo(2, function() { $("#novaTela").show(2000); });

$("#telaAntiga").hide(2000, proxy(0)); // Primeiro evento assíncrono

$.getJSON(url, data, proxy(1, function(json) { return json; })); // Segundo evento
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/68jAT/3/).

Answer (score 3):

Complementando o exemplo do Jordão, você poderia usar também o objeto jQuery.Deferred alem de fazer alguns testes no $.when para ter certeza que tudo foi executado corretamente e dai sim resolver esse Deferred e executar o código. O funcionamento é similar, porem é interessante separar os conceitos.

```
ready = $.Deferred();

$.when(animacao, json)
  .done(animacaoResposta, jsonResposta, function() {
    if(jsonReposta[0].error) {
      console.log(jsonReposta[0].error);
    }
    else {
      ready.resolve();
    }
  })
  .fail(function() {
      console.log('Alguma coisa deu errado');
  });

ready.done(function () {
    // executa seu código com certeza que tudo deu certo
});
```

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/gilbarbara/xNL7J/1/