# Executar uma ação após o change ter sido feito

Tags: javascript, jquery

Não sei se existe essa possibilidade, mas gostaria de saber se tem como executar uma determinada ação após a ação do `change` de um `select`.

Vamos supor que eu tenho um `select` assim:

```
<select name="meuSelect" id="meuSelect">
    <option value="0">Selecione</option>
    <option value="1">Primeiro item</option>
    <option value="2">Segundo item</option>
</select>
```

e com o jQuery para eu executar algo quando o usuário seleciona um item eu pego assim:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#meuSelect").change(function() {
        // executa uma ação qualquer
        console.log('executou tudo por exemplo');
    });

    //somente executar a proxima ação após ter concluido tudo do 'change'
    //pensando que essa ação do change esta em outro arquivo 
    //e esta sendo chamado por um $(seletor).on('change', function(){});
    //coloquei aqui somente como exemplo, mas o change aqui não existe

    console.log('Agora sim');
});
```

Espero que tenha sido claro nos comentários, explicando um pouco melhor meu problema

Comment: Marcelo, percebi pelos comentários da resposta dada pelo João Paulo que o que você está fazendo é uma requisição assíncrona. Nesse tipo de requisição o seu código de callback deve estar logo após a requisição ao servidor senão não vai funcionar de forma adequada.

Comment: O post seguinte talvez te ajude: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/como-executar-uma-funcao-apos-dois-ou-mais-eventos-assincronos

Answer (score 2):

Cria outra função change na página, depois da referencia a esse script externo.

Veja como funciona: http://jsfiddle.net/johnflaster/Tavb5/1/

Exemplo:

```
<script src="script_externo.js">

<script>

$(document).on("change", "#meuSelect", function(){
    console.log('Isso sera executado depois do primeiro change, por causa da ordem em que foi colocado na pagina');
});

</script>
```

Comment: Então eu cheguei a fazer isso mas não funcionou pois eu carrego esse html com um ajax e com isso vem esse js que executa o que eu disse, sei que não é a melhor forma, mas é uma que consegui, mas acabei travando ai

Comment: Troca $("#meuSelect").change(function(){ por $(document).on("change", "#meuSelect", function(){. Que ai o change funcionara pra elementos criados dinamicamente.

Comment: já tinha testado assim também e nada... acho que irei ter que arrumar as chamadas para que isso realmente funcione da forma correta. Ainda assim obrigado.

Comment: Quando você vai no console do navegador (F12) ele apresenta algum erro de javascript? Pode colar aqui?

Comment: Se puder postar o codigo real com a chamada do codigo externo e com o seu js também ajuda. De repente tem algum erro bobo no meio.

Comment: Não apresenta erro algum. Fiz alguns testes e nada. Como comentei, pode ser um erro de criação minha, assim eu espero que com isso eu tenho que trabalhar um pouco melhor nisso.

Answer (score 1):

É só encapsular em uma função, só pra manter a organização, e então chamar a function dentro do seu callback:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function doAfterChange(){
        console.log('Agora sim');
    }

    $("#meuSelect").change(function() {
        // executa uma ação qualquer
        console.log('executou tudo por exemplo');

        // Lá vai:
        doAfterChange();
    });
});
```

Comment: Entendi o que passou, mas não irei poder alterar a função externa que faz o change, mas ainda assim obrigado

Comment: Ah, agora entendi o que você escreveu lá em cima :)
Bom, pena que não solucionou, vou ficar de olho pra aprender mais essa também ^^